# Divergence theorem hypothesis

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I have the following question about the Divergence theorem. 
I've seen in my class book the following:
**Divergence Theorem:** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$  be a symmetric elemental region and $\partial\Omega$ a closed surface with normal orientation. Let $F=(P,Q,R)$ be a differentiable field then,
$$\iiint_\Omega \operatorname{div} F \,dx\, dy \,dz = \iint_{\partial\Omega} F \cdot ds.$$

On the proof given as $\Omega$ is symmetric elemental region there are $\phi_1(x,y)$ and $\phi_2(x,y)$ such that $\Omega=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}: (x,y)\in D, \phi_1(x,y) \leq z \leq \phi_2(x,y)\}$

And the calculates  $\iint_{S_1} (0,0,R) ds$

where $S_1$ is the surface with parametrization $T(x,y)=(x,y,\phi_1(x,y)).$
But to use this parametrization for calculating the integral it's necessary to differentiate $\phi_1$ and in the book, it assumes that the derivative exists and finishes the proof from there.

I have two question, first is that I don't see why I can assume that the derivative exists if I don't have the hypothesis of $\partial\Omega$ being piecewise smooth.
Second, are there surfaces where the theorem does not apply?

Comment: "derivate"  Do you mean "differentiate"?  Just checking.

Comment: partial derivates of $\phi_i$

Comment: Should perhaps the integrand in the second member of the equation be $F\cdot\nu$? Or is it $F\cdot\mathrm{d}{\boldsymbol{s}}$ meaning with $\mathrm{d}{\boldsymbol{s}}$ the so called "surface area element", i.e. the vector product $\mathrm{d}s_1\times\mathrm{d}s_2$ where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are local parametrization on $\partial\Omega$? I am asking this since the integral at the first member is a scalar, while the one at the second member can be misunderstand as a vector.

Comment: Thanks for adding the $\cdot$: now the notation is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumptions can be weakened somewhat, but a minimum of regularity is needed for the very formulation of the divergence theorem. How did you construct the surface element $ds$? If you check that construction you will see that it involves derivatives of the parameterization $\phi$.

The necessity of some regularity to construct the surface element is more easily seen in the one-dimensional case. Peano's curves are maps $\phi\colon [0, 1]\to [0,1]\times[0, 1]$ that are continuous and surjective. This means that you can parameterize the square, a $2$ dimensional object, with a single parameter. But certainly you cannot construct a "line element" on the square. This is no surprise, as Peano's curves are not differentiable at any point.

Comment: Let me see if I understood, you're saying that I need some regularity for even the surface integral to be defined. And that regularity includes derivates of $\phi$ so then it will be correct to say that when I do the calculation the derivates vanish so it's not really important if $\phi$ has derivates in all its domain and the result follows? And this would imply that Gauss theorem works for every region that makes sense to integrate its boundary?

Comment: To eliminate all doubt, please write down the expression of the surface element in terms of $\phi$. It contains derivatives, so you need derivatives for the integral to even be defined, as you said. However, there are workarounds: if the derivatives cease to exist on a measure zero set, chances are that this will not affect the result. This kind of calculus with low regularity is done in books in geometric measure theory, it is awfully complicated, but it always starts with a proof in the regular case. So at a pedagogical level the *right* theorem yo study is the regular one.